# Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions with turf.mask() for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, polygon, geojson, turfjs

I am trying to use [turf.mask()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#mask) on these two polygons: [state](https://easyupload.io/ra5cu7) and [hexagon](https://easyupload.io/fs32ui).

```
state = {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-122.5399362859679,37.830838250358305],[-122.5352992,37.8292543],[-122.5360944,37.8239044],[-122.5279709,37.8153353],[-122.5292904,37.8198549],[-122.5229995,37.8251486],[-122.5099818,37.8245382],[-122.4995901,37.8199115],[-122.4907812,37.8266974],[-122.478306,37.8254268],[-122.47823831099781,37.83244271995018],[-122.5399362859679,37.83244271995018],[-122.5399362859679,37.830838250358305]]],[[[-122.5209211,37.5943953],[-122.5172512,37.5892786],[-122.5205505,37.5739919],[-122.5144188,37.5657519],[-122.5135889,37.5559887],[-122.5197357,37.5371873],[-122.5179299,37.5238199],[-122.5118361,37.5131343],[-122.4987459,37.5009924],[-122.4993886,37.4956524],[-122.4934399,37.4929939],[-122.4845619,37.493956],[-122.4933403,37.4931535],[-122.4963325,37.4978499],[-122.4870092,37.5037473],[-122.4837393,37.5005349],[-122.485041,37.5028707],[-122.4795964,37.5033699],[-122.4805619,37.5005397],[-122.4770952,37.5024601],[-122.4745322,37.5006196],[-122.4858172,37.49523],[-122.4706747,37.5007852],[-122.4584325,37.4908973],[-122.4508972389485,37.47800498084561],[-122.2721445405403,37.47800498084561],[-122.2721445405403,37.57062405456298],[-122.2734391,37.5701746],[-122.2845216,37.5757537],[-122.2915515,37.5743495],[-122.2933973,37.5691119],[-122.2968954,37.5755277],[-122.305437,37.5749218],[-122.316048,37.5840024],[-122.3139154,37.5900472],[-122.3165712,37.5867603],[-122.3173273,37.5903678],[-122.3177269,37.5867609],[-122.318293,37.5911926],[-122.3145503,37.5923252],[-122.3325163,37.5877861],[-122.3344629,37.5920779],[-122.3380163,37.5920507],[-122.3384833,37.5871208],[-122.3579245,37.5888057],[-122.3383946,37.5882378],[-122.3384111,37.5919623],[-122.3459053,37.5898998],[-122.3439243,37.5920571],[-122.360012,37.592015],[-122.3640642,37.598455],[-122.3786677,37.6059181],[-122.3713687,37.6147206],[-122.3582017,37.6089833],[-122.3548517,37.6148603],[-122.3681936,37.6210318],[-122.3653327,37.6281401],[-122.3736554,37.6279567],[-122.3789373,37.6315371],[-122.3861757,37.6288252],[-122.3878968,37.634473],[-122.3796783,37.6351943],[-122.3837736,37.6399334],[-122.3911844,37.6391024],[-122.3909661,37.6444244],[-122.3917268,37.6390208],[-122.3965553,37.6388167],[-122.3934705,37.6438287],[-122.3992832,37.642004],[-122.4028452,37.6426094],[-122.4013169,37.6461099],[-122.3994533,37.6431429],[-122.396963,37.6427665],[-122.3917379,37.6477991],[-122.3803373,37.648125],[-122.3755326,37.6549592],[-122.3799605,37.6607485],[-122.3744577,37.6624522],[-122.3829018,37.6631099],[-122.3811718,37.6681459],[-122.3859696,37.667591],[-122.3869568,37.6645382],[-122.3952727,37.6650535],[-122.3874281,37.6716869],[-122.3810763,37.6718878],[-122.3811199,37.6773246],[-122.3878163,37.6783848],[-122.3941205,37.7073575],[-122.3914199,37.7096391],[-122.3744129,37.7086766],[-122.3800854,37.7106027],[-122.3759862,37.7160655],[-122.3869772,37.7242593],[-122.3808547,37.7217156],[-122.3768873,37.7239002],[-122.3738477,37.7188103],[-122.3654008,37.7160347],[-122.3627284,37.7200714],[-122.3590965,37.7193159],[-122.3652453,37.7256766],[-122.3577914,37.7246098],[-122.3616456,37.7251817],[-122.3569649,37.728662],[-122.3622605,37.7284968],[-122.3588648,37.7297956],[-122.3658749,37.7331392],[-122.3754819,37.7328043],[-122.3764548,37.739765],[-122.3732029,37.7372296],[-122.3675347,37.7382209],[-122.3735546,37.7386854],[-122.3676515,37.740137],[-122.3752341,37.7468542],[-122.3929128,37.7474166],[-122.3757592,37.7487044],[-122.3761037,37.752267],[-122.3841093,37.7546193],[-122.3808144,37.755204],[-122.3838352,37.7620693],[-122.3810399,37.762589],[-122.3870406,37.7637898],[-122.3856126,37.7702142],[-122.3831784,37.7697199],[-122.3867755,37.7732761],[-122.381492,37.7719454],[-122.381849,37.7746281],[-122.3869477,37.7743538],[-122.3850142,37.776339],[-122.3899459,37.7766762],[-122.398671,37.7705013],[-122.3902987,37.7772108],[-122.3874581,37.7783059],[-122.3877716,37.7822999],[-122.3847049,37.7825645],[-122.3876263,37.7854527],[-122.3845243,37.7873797],[-122.3874381,37.7872449],[-122.3852995,37.7898012],[-122.3976619,37.7998545],[-122.3957218,37.8014672],[-122.3983318,37.8006011],[-122.3971208,37.8030526],[-122.3997229,37.8021723],[-122.3985174,37.8045967],[-122.4009866,37.8035636],[-122.4003819,37.8072585],[-122.4028024,37.8060243],[-122.4043847,37.8088919],[-122.4053268,37.8068875],[-122.4104297,37.811425],[-122.4105114,37.8087706],[-122.4203547,37.8115306],[-122.4163293,37.80833],[-122.4228214,37.8102504],[-122.4210749,37.8085664],[-122.424679,37.8066449],[-122.4301758,37.809232],[-122.4328481,37.8057039],[-122.435879,37.8075603],[-122.4473666,37.8055087],[-122.440031,37.808853],[-122.4632009,37.8050656],[-122.4777987,37.8109716],[-122.4869244,37.789907],[-122.5059955,37.7881687],[-122.5147128,37.7811281],[-122.5070212,37.7235595],[-122.4963102,37.6820786],[-122.4941412,37.6435021],[-122.4960688,37.6232689],[-122.4990205,37.6201788],[-122.4969547,37.6120108],[-122.5020589,37.6067327],[-122.5006007,37.6013344],[-122.5060876,37.5963957],[-122.5149418,37.5987038],[-122.5151511,37.5958341],[-122.5209211,37.5943953]]],[[[-122.47454130078302,37.83244271995018],[-122.4727523,37.8320753],[-122.4726672512427,37.83244271995018],[-122.47454130078302,37.83244271995018]]],[[[-122.379047,37.8267146],[-122.3713678,37.8151916],[-122.3727963,37.8108587],[-122.3619928,37.8070656],[-122.3589024,37.8147697],[-122.3672433,37.8122518],[-122.3704001,37.8142932],[-122.3629308,37.8226056],[-122.3686209,37.8310775],[-122.3733669,37.8322631],[-122.379047,37.8267146]]],[[[-122.3426269,37.8057313],[-122.3413237,37.803655],[-122.3249395,37.8067225],[-122.3252406,37.8000102],[-122.330053,37.799951],[-122.3055583,37.7937247],[-122.2805644,37.7957313],[-122.2721445405403,37.79148781862211],[-122.2721445405403,37.83244271995018],[-122.29662795299252,37.83244271995018],[-122.2950082,37.8292417],[-122.3055254,37.826014],[-122.3148745,37.8257845],[-122.3119885,37.82721],[-122.3160071,37.8278395],[-122.3214924,37.8230959],[-122.3300331,37.8216442],[-122.3188547,37.8187413],[-122.3151503,37.8218637],[-122.3083022,37.8210817],[-122.322915,37.8101466],[-122.3330683,37.8110303],[-122.3426269,37.8057313]]],[[[-122.3316381,37.7814097],[-122.3075012,37.7760617],[-122.3082387,37.7803977],[-122.298304,37.7800123],[-122.3011353,37.7742605],[-122.2914341,37.7681259],[-122.2815741,37.7711087],[-122.280682,37.7662999],[-122.276538,37.768255],[-122.2721445405403,37.76325713296079],[-122.2721445405403,37.78664847083194],[-122.2783834,37.7918049],[-122.3005534,37.790309],[-122.3314733,37.7968291],[-122.3316381,37.7814097]]],[[[-122.2887255,37.7656186],[-122.2827173,37.763773],[-122.2871204,37.7658696],[-122.2842014,37.7673989],[-122.2860548,37.7695738],[-122.2887255,37.7656186]]]]}}

hex = {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-121.91508032705622,37.271355866731895],[-121.86222328902491,37.353926450852256],[-121.92354999630157,37.42834118609435],[-122.03773496427027,37.42012867767778],[-122.09042892904397,37.33755608435298],[-122.02910130918998,37.26319797461824],[-121.91508032705622,37.271355866731895]]],[[[-122.09042892904397,37.33755608435298],[-122.03773496427027,37.42012867767778],[-122.0991572595036,37.49436145881944],[-122.21327339445754,37.485965058551095],[-122.2658032483195,37.4033911145053],[-122.20438138645652,37.32921488696578],[-122.09042892904397,37.33755608435298]]],[[[-122.2658032483195,37.4033911145053],[-122.21327339445754,37.485965058551095],[-122.27479015180235,37.560015298456165],[-122.38883528966466,37.551435083769555],[-122.44120000376466,37.46886044817503],[-122.37968502627967,37.39486668388987],[-122.2658032483195,37.4033911145053]]],[[[-122.27479015180235,37.560015298456165],[-122.2221915863209,37.64251820979243],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.45044537747678,37.625302208372474],[-122.38883528966466,37.551435083769555],[-122.27479015180235,37.560015298456165]]],[[[-122.44120000376466,37.46886044817503],[-122.38883528966466,37.551435083769555],[-122.45044537747678,37.625302208372474],[-122.56441735732743,37.61653827043709],[-122.61661591173977,37.53396360310495],[-122.55500895066726,37.46015287008624],[-122.44120000376466,37.46886044817503]]],[[[-122.45044537747678,37.625302208372474],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.57385345315238,37.77272521206777],[-122.62611963828853,37.69022171873274],[-122.56441735732743,37.61653827043709],[-122.45044537747678,37.625302208372474]]],[[[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.23113607743653,37.79887236738518],[-122.29284349699644,37.872667939497596],[-122.4072167465147,37.863976689425115],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208]]],[[[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.23113607743653,37.79887236738518],[-122.29284349699644,37.872667939497596],[-122.4072167465147,37.863976689425115],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208]]],[[[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.23113607743653,37.79887236738518],[-122.29284349699644,37.872667939497596],[-122.4072167465147,37.863976689425115],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208]]],[[[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.23113607743653,37.79887236738518],[-122.29284349699644,37.872667939497596],[-122.4072167465147,37.863976689425115],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208]]],[[[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.23113607743653,37.79887236738518],[-122.29284349699644,37.872667939497596],[-122.4072167465147,37.863976689425115],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208]]],[[[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.23113607743653,37.79887236738518],[-122.29284349699644,37.872667939497596],[-122.4072167465147,37.863976689425115],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208]]],[[[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208],[-122.23113607743653,37.79887236738518],[-122.29284349699644,37.872667939497596],[-122.4072167465147,37.863976689425115],[-122.4597179789842,37.781545330604914],[-122.39801249019256,37.707805739822945],[-122.28380352912619,37.71644156150208]]]]}}
```

I can visualize them on geojson.io. They are correctly visualized there.
However, when I try to run

```
mask(hex, state);
```

I am getting

> Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions.

Which I do not understand.... Why can't it mask the polygon?

Answer (score 0):

One cannot use two multipolygons with `turf.mask()`. The first argument of `turf.mask()` can be a polygon or multipolygon. But the second argument must be a polygon, not a multipolygon!